# Where can I find data on of total labor costs of a company vs their profits/return to capital?

Tags: wages, data, accounting, capital-returns, labor-cost

I'd like to find out how much a company spends on labor (wages, benefits, tax-withholding, etc).

Is this information available on, e.g. yahoo finance or similar websites or in some standard reports that companies publish every year. What are the terms I should be looking up?

I would like to compare the amount spent on labor per year to the return paid to capital, i.e. the amount of profit/dividends/(whatever the relevant quantity is) that is paid out to shareholders.

I don't know the right terminology here so any clarifications of these ideas are greatly appreciated. Basically, I would like to understand quantitatively the breakdown between money flowing labor and to "capital".